# Updating table after delete (axios, react, express)

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I'm working on a CRUD app with MySQL, React, Express, and Axios.

This is the last part but I can't seem to figure out how to refresh my table data after the record is deleted. I've tried updating the state in the .then() as well as directly after the function call. If I update the state with a different year/manager it works properly but I would like to just refresh the manager/year data that is currently active. I've never posted a code sample this long so I hope it isn't too much but I really didn't want to miss anything.

Of note, I'm using react-table so the way I handle the "only one checkbox may be selected at a time" is kind of odd.

```js
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo, forwardRef, useRef } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useSortBy, useTable, useRowSelect } from "react-table";
import "./KeeperTable.css";

const KeeperTable = (props) => {
  const [playersList, setPlayersList] = useState([]);
  const [url, setUrl] = useState("/getData");

  const data = useMemo(() => playersList, [playersList]);

  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "Manager",
        accessor: "manager",
      },
      {
        Header: "Player",
        accessor: "player_name",
      },
      {
        Header: "Year",
        accessor: "year",
      },
      {
        Header: "Retained",
        accessor: "drafts_retained",
      },
      {
        Header: "Remain",
        accessor: "drafts_remaining",
      },
    ],
    []
  );

  const IndeterminateCheckbox = forwardRef(
    ({ indeterminate, ...rest }, ref) => {
      const defaultRef = useRef();
      const resolvedRef = ref || defaultRef;

      useEffect(() => {
        resolvedRef.current.indeterminate = indeterminate;
      }, [resolvedRef, indeterminate]);

      return (
        <>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            name="myCheckbox"
            ref={resolvedRef}
            {...rest}
          />
        </>
      );
    }
  );

  const handleDeleteClick = () => {
    let checkedCount = 0;
    let manager = "";
    let player = "";
    let year = "";

    //Gets the data from selected row
    let rows = document.getElementsByName("myCheckbox");
    for (let row of rows) {
      row.checked && checkedCount++;
      if (row.checked) {
        manager = row.parentNode.parentNode.nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
        player =
          row.parentNode.parentNode.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling
            .innerHTML;
        year =
          row.parentNode.parentNode.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling
            .nextElementSibling.innerHTML;
      }
    }

    //if more than one row is selected stop, else make the call to deletePlayerRecord
    if (checkedCount >= 2 || checkedCount <= 0) {
      console.log("only delete one record at a time!");
    } else {
      async function deletePlayerRecord() {
        axios
          .post("/deletePlayer", {
            year: year,
            manager: manager,
            player: player,
          })
          .then((res) => {
            setUrl(`/getData/${year}/${manager}`);
          });
      }
      //call the function then update the state which should refresh the table. url variable has a useEffect that updates the playersList date which in turn has a
      //use effect to make a new axios call and get the proper data.
      console.log("clicked");
      deletePlayerRecord();
    }
  };

  const { getTableProps, getTableBodyProps, headerGroups, rows, prepareRow } =
    useTable(
      {
        columns,
        data,
      },
      useSortBy,
      useRowSelect,
      (hooks) => {
        hooks.visibleColumns.push((columns) => [
          // Let's make a column for selection
          {
            id: "selection",
            Header: ({ getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps }) => (
              <div>
                <button onClick={handleDeleteClick} className="btn-primary">
                  X
                </button>
              </div>
            ),
            // The cell can use the individual row's getToggleRowSelectedProps method
            // to the render a checkbox
            Cell: ({ row }) => (
              <div>
                <IndeterminateCheckbox {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()} />
              </div>
            ),
          },
          ...columns,
        ]);
      }
    );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.yearSearch !== "#" && props.teamSearch !== "#") {
      setUrl(`/getData/${props.yearSearch}/${props.teamSearch}`);
    }
  }, [props.yearSearch, props.teamSearch]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getTeams() {
      axios.get(url).then((res) => {
        setPlayersList(res.data);
      });
    }
    getTeams();
  }, [url]);

  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <table id="keepers" {...getTableProps()}>
        <thead>
          {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
            <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
              {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                <th {...column.getHeaderProps(column.getSortByToggleProps())}>
                  {column.render("Header")}
                </th>
              ))}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </thead>
        <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
          {rows.map((row) => {
            prepareRow(row);
            return (
              <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                {row.cells.map((cell) => {
                  return (
                    <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render("Cell")}</td>
                  );
                })}
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default KeeperTable;
```

[image: Table after delete]

If you would like to see the server side code I can post it but I do not think it is relavent as the delete does work properly it is just the table refreshing after that I can't seem to get.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to re-invoke your `getTeams()` operation after the delete?

Comment: Essentially yes I think this is what I'm looking for. I thought I could just set the state of the url which would trigger the useEffect that the getTeams() function is in. Because it is listening to changes to the url state.

Comment: Does that URL change?  If the value doesn't change then it won't trigger the `useEffect`.  Though it may make more sense to move `getTeams` into the component scope so you can call it from other operations.

Comment: Yeah it does change because for example if I hardcode the values "setUrl(`/getData/2021/Dan`);" in its place, it properly refreshes the table data to reflect that, after a delete. It is only when trying to refresh the table you are viewing that the data doesn't reload. For example, if I'm viewing Cory- 2022 and delete a player from that table, the delete works as evidenced by the record being deleted from the database but the front end doesn't reflect this.

Comment: I've tried moving getTeams() to component scope and it refreshes the data but brings you to the master list with every manager/player after the delete. Not the specific manager you were on.

Comment: seems like something to do with the url useState.  When the setState is hardcoded it works, when I console.log(console.log(`/getData/${year}/${manager}`) it displays the proper info, but when I combine the two setUrl(`/getData/${year}/${manager}`); and call the getTeams() function which uses the url. It console.logs to getData// from the function.

Comment: Called a different axios.get after the delete that uses useRef instead of state. This appears to have solved my issue.